# How can I distribute beta builds of App and not write over purchases copies

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I believe I understand out to produce an .ipa file for Ad Hoc distribution to my beta testers, but my question is what settings do I need to allow the beta copy to co-exist with a purchased copy of my App on the same device?  That way they can test out the app for me, and fall back to the production app for day to day use.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the bundle identifier. For your app is com.domainname.appname, for your beta could be com.domainname.appname-beta

Comment: So I would create another AppID on the Provisioning Portal page for the beta, setup the Ad Hoc provisioning profiles for that beta app, and make the changes in Xcode in the bundle identifier and text name.  Then when I'm ready to go to production, I would just change the bundle ID and name text back before archiving and submitting to the App Store for review?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new app name and bundle identifier and then name the app (the text under the icon) a different name then send it out. It's a little extra work but it makes it so you won't mess up any existing saved data on your production app.